# Read error while installing DraftSight in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-installation

```
root@porjecta:/# gdebi draftSight.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 

With DraftSight, you can easily create professional CAD drawings. Supported file formats are DWT, DXF and DWG.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
(Reading database ... 213876 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dassault-systemes-draftsight (from draftSight.deb) ...
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: invalid stored block lengths'
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'draftSight.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to write (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing draftSight.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/dassault-systemes/draftsight/Help/korean/korean.qch' to '/opt/dassault-systemes/draftsight/Help/korean/korean.qch.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 draftSight.deb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two commands on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get clean
gdebi draftSight.deb
```

If not worked,try to redownload the `draftSight.deb` file after running  `sudo apt-get clean`.

Comment: ok i have to install draft sight in 16 pc's then i have to download draftsight 16 times?????

Comment: still shows the same error!

Comment: yes..it shows same error message

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get clean` then `sudo dpkg -i draftSight.deb`

Comment: No luck for me.....it shows th same error..:(

Comment: check that md5sum was same for draftsight.deb file by running `md5sum draftSight.deb`